# How do I find an Azure App Registration's AppId from Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to allow users of my app to query AzureAD to find the App Registration that the app will use to request tokens with.

This would be an infrequent flow because once they've found the correct App Registration I save it into the user's app.settings and move on.

I understand how to hit the Graph and get the tokens I need once I have the App Registration; I  have used Graph Explorer to verify I can use REST To find the App Reg I need.

Where I am struggling is how to get that token I need to query the Graph -- Help!

What I'm trying to avoid is the users forgetting/losing/not knowing/.. the appId and having to ping helpdesk/IT/.. to ask what it is.

Comment: Which api are you getting tokens for? From your question, I do not quite understand your needs.

Comment: Do you want to ask which application requested the token?

Comment: I am trying to get a token for an api provided by an Enterprise App. I have an app registration created which allows user_impersonation to that api. What I want to do is to query Azure/the Graph to find the AppID of the app registration so I can use it.

Comment: Why don't you ask your admin to gather the client id of azure ad app which has the api permission of that enterprise app?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid calls to helpdesk. This is a trivial thing to do with PowerShell (Connect-AzureAD; Get-AzureADApplication). Surely it's not impossible with C#.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if you only find the application in the tenant based on `user_impersonation` permissions, it is almost impossible or very troublesome. First, you need to use graph api to list all the applications in the tenant, and then traverse the applications.

Next, you need to use graph api to list all the permissions granted to each application, and then you can lock a certain applications or certain applications based on `user_impersonation` permissions (because other applications may also be granted user_impersonation permissions).

Therefore, I do not recommend you to do this, I think the easiest way is to contact your administrator, which can save a lot of coding process.

Comment: I have a number of ways of traversing the app registrations to find the one I care about - honestly that is not a problem I am worried about solving at all. The problem I am trying to solve is 'How do I get a list of app registrations?'. I know my user(s) have permissions to do this as the savvy ones can do it easily with PowerShell.

Comment: @David  Use [list applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to list all applications, and then check the `requiredResourceAccess` parameter.

Comment: thanks @CarlZhao -- that looks about right. However, I am struggling to get an authentication token to be be able to make that call. I've used this API in graph explorer and it gives me the info I need. In Graph Explorer I click the 'Sign in to Graph Explorer' button to get the token. It's that 'Sign in to Graph Explorer' step that I need to emulate in my C# app.